# Adding an Under-brace Under a Label, `tikz`

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles, underbrace

I'd like to add add an (under)brace under the labels in the following diagram, indicating the part of the structure labeled "A" and "B", respectively. What I have makes the brace too close to the actual structure:

```
 \documentclass[10pt]{beamer}
 \usepackage{tikz}
 \usetikzlibrary{calc}
 \usetikzlibrary{patterns}
 \usetikzlibrary{matrix,decorations.pathreplacing}
 \begin{document}
 \begin{frame}
 \begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw[blue] (0,0) grid (3,2);

  \draw[pattern=dots, pattern color=blue, draw=blue](2,0)rectangle+(1,1);
   \draw[pattern=dots, pattern color=blue, draw=blue](2,1)rectangle+(1,1);



   \path [(0,2) --  (2,2)];

   \draw [decoration=brace, decorate] (0, 2.west |-0,2) -- (2,2.east |-0,2)
        node [midway, above=.25ex, font=\footnotesize] {A};

    \path [(2,2) --  (3,2)];
    \draw [decoration=brace, decorate] (2, 2.west |-2,2) -- (3,2.east |-3,2)
        node [midway, above=.25ex, font=\footnotesize] {B};


 \end{tikzpicture}\hspace*{3em}
 \end{frame}
 \end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Braces can be raised with `raise`. Since I didn't quite understand if you want overbrace or underbrace, I add both options (and removed several errors from the code).

```
\documentclass[10pt]{beamer}
 \usepackage{tikz}
 \usetikzlibrary{calc}
 \usetikzlibrary{patterns}
 \usetikzlibrary{matrix,decorations.pathreplacing}
 \begin{document}
 \begin{frame}
 \begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw[blue] (0,0) grid (3,2);

  \draw[pattern=dots, pattern color=blue, draw=blue](2,0)rectangle+(1,1);
   \draw[pattern=dots, pattern color=blue, draw=blue](2,1)rectangle+(1,1);

   \path (0,2) --  (2,2);

   \draw [decoration={brace,raise=1pt}, decorate,thick] (0, 2) -- (2,2)
        node [midway, above=.25ex, font=\footnotesize] {A};

    \path (2,2) --  (3,2);
    \draw [decoration={brace,raise=1pt}, decorate,thick] (2, 2) -- (3,2)
        node [midway, above=.25ex, font=\footnotesize] {B};


 \end{tikzpicture}
 \begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw[blue] (0,0) grid (3,2);

  \draw[pattern=dots, pattern color=blue, draw=blue](2,0)rectangle+(1,1);
   \draw[pattern=dots, pattern color=blue, draw=blue](2,1)rectangle+(1,1);

   \path (0,2) --  (2,2);

   \draw [decoration={brace,raise=1pt,mirror}, decorate,thick] (0,0) -- (2,0)
        node [midway,below=.25ex, font=\footnotesize] {A};

    \path (2,2) --  (3,2);
    \draw [decoration={brace,raise=1pt,mirror}, decorate,thick] (2,0) -- (3,0)
        node [midway,below=.25ex, font=\footnotesize] {B};


 \end{tikzpicture}
 \end{frame}
 \end{document}
```

[image]